# ANOVA table for alpha latice design?

Tags: anova, experiment-design

I have my trail in ***alpha lattice design*** with three replications, 32 blocks in each replication, 10 plots per block, and with 320 treatment, please suggest to me an ANOVA model for this analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The model will be
$Y_{ijk} = \mu + R_i + B_{ij} + T_k + e_{ijk} $
where
$\mu = \text{General mean}$, 
$R_i = \text{(fixed) effect of Replicate $i$}$, 
$B_{ij} = \text{(random) effect of Block $j$ within Replicate $i$}$,
$T_k = \text{Effect of treatment $k$ [this could be random or fixed]}$.

This model can be fitted using residual maximum likelihood (ReML).

Comment: Welcome to our site! However, you should learn to use math markup $\LaTeX$ in your posts.